# Multiple Updates and Multiple Transactions vs one Transaction

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Using MySQL, in one routine via JDBC I'm updating a great number of records (every record in the table). Each update has its own transaction.

How much efficiency, if any, would I buy if I grouped all of the updates into one transaction?

Are there other advantages, besides speed, to perform minimal transactions? i.e. how much overhead is there per xaction?

Comment: Run a benchmark and see.

Comment: How systematic vs ad hoc are the updates? If you can avoid client-DBMS traffic, it will be a big win; if you end up with the same amount of client-DBMS traffic, it will be a wash.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thanks for your response. They are systematic and are indeed done on the client. "big win" would be nice :)

Comment: Can you do the updates in the server (as a single UPDATE statement that runs only in the server)?  If so, then you have your 'big win' available.  If the updates are systematic, you may well be able to do it.  If it means you need to create and populate a temporary table to allow you to do the update in the server, you probably still have a fairly decent win available.  If you absolutely cannot do the update solely in the server, then you may not have a win available.  So, the ideal is a single UPDATE statement. A second option might be a stored procedure that handles the UPDATE statements.

Comment: Either of those avoids relaying data back and forth between DBMS and client, and both therefore give you a big win.  Communication back and forth is more expensive than operations within the DBMS.  This applies to essentially any DBMS (though SQLite comes closest to reducing the cost of client-DBMS communications — at a cost in resiliency, etc).